# PeerFinder instability

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, wifi

This is my first post on Stack Overflow because I always search through the web before post a problem on a website. However, I'm stuck on an app feature since more than 2 weeks.

Context:
    OS: Windows 8.1
    Target: For now Dell Venue 11 pro (with WiFi drivers from the September the 1st of 2014) but the final target is Dell Venue 8 pro
    Language: .NET 4.5.1 (C#)
    App type: WinRT Store Application

The Goal:
I want to design an app that can connect through WiFi Direct to another app in order to transfert messages (byte data). 
I use a DistacherTimer(every 4) to deal with all PeerFinder steps.
Here are the steps of the DispatcherTimer method :
    1 - BrowseForPeers (i use await PeerFinder.FindAllPeerAsync();)
    2 - Accept connection from the requestingpeers: opening 1 connection, receiving message then closing the connection. Requesting peers are registered in an observable collection using ConnectionRequested event of PeerFinder.
    3 - SendMessage stored in the queue: for each peer in the browsed peers => connect, send, close (one at a time)

My problem:
When i start my application on both tablets, the first message is transfered successfully. However, I can't send another one because I run through many different errors: connection timed out, connection refused, device or resource isn't not in the correct state, device is not correctly attached...

I don't understand where the problem is. I tried many things.
Here is a sample of the code :

```
//Code used for accept the connection of one peer and receive message
using (var socket = await PeerFinder.ConnectAsync(peer))
{
    if (socket != null)
    {
        DisplayStatus("Connection Accepted...");

        var message = NetworkMessage.Deserialize(await _socketHelper.ReceiveMessage(socket));
        message.SenderId = peer.Id;
        OnReceiveMessage(message);

        socket.Dispose();
    }
}

//Code used for connecting to a peer and send message
using (var socket = await PeerFinder.ConnectAsync(pPeerInformation))
{
    var messageData = NetworkMessage.Serialize(pMessage);

    DisplayStatus("Sending message...");
    success = await _socketHelper.SendMessage(messageData, socket, pMessage.Id);

    socket.Dispose();
}

//Code used for receiving the data
//pSocket is the socket defined by PeerFinder.ConnectAsync
using (var socketWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(pSocket.OutputStream))
{
    using (var socketReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(pSocket.InputStream))
    {
        OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(0, 4, "Accept connection"));
        socketWriter.WriteByte(1);
        await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
        await socketWriter.FlushAsync();


        OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(1, 4, "Waiting for message ID"));
        var count = await socketReader.LoadAsync(16);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            socketWriter.WriteByte(0);
            await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
            await socketWriter.FlushAsync();                                
            return new byte[0];
         }
         var dataId = new byte[16];
         socketReader.ReadBytes(dataId);

         if (IdLogs.Contains(dataId))
         {
             socketWriter.WriteByte(100);
             OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(4, 4, "Message already receive, closing connection"));
             await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
             await socketWriter.FlushAsync();
             return new byte[0];
          }

          IdLogs.Add(dataId);

          OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(2, 4, "Accepting message"));
          socketWriter.WriteByte(2);
          await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
          await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

          OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(2, 4, "Waiting for message size"));
          count = await socketReader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
          if (count == 0)
          {
              socketWriter.WriteByte(0);
              await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
              await socketWriter.FlushAsync();
              return new byte[0];
          }

          var size = socketReader.ReadUInt32();

          OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(3, 4, "Size : " + size));
          socketWriter.WriteByte(3);
          await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
          await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

          OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(4, 4, "Downloading message"));

          uint sum = 0;
          var totalData = new List<byte>();
          while (sum < size)
          {
              count = await socketReader.LoadAsync(size);
              if (count == 0)
              {
                  socketWriter.WriteByte(0);
                  await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
                  await socketWriter.FlushAsync();
                  return new byte[0];
              }

              var tempData = new byte[count];
              socketReader.ReadBytes(tempData);

              sum += count;

              totalData.AddRange(tempData);

              OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(sum, size, "Data downloaded"));
          }

          OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(4, 4, "Download finished"));
          socketWriter.WriteByte(4);
          await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
          await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

          socketReader.DetachStream();
          socketWriter.DetachStream();

          socketWriter.Dispose();
          socketReader.Dispose();

          return totalData.ToArray();
      }
 }

 //Code used to send data
 //pSocket is the socket defined by PeerFinder.ConnectAsync
 using (var socketWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(pSocket.OutputStream))
 {
     using (var socketReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(pSocket.InputStream))
     {
         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(0, 4, "Waiting for connection acceptance"));
         var signal = await ReadSignal(socketReader);
         if (signal != 1)
         {
             return false;
         }

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(1, 4, "Sending ID"));
         socketWriter.WriteBytes(pId);
         await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
         await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(1, 4, "Waiting for ID acceptance"));
         signal = await ReadSignal(socketReader);
         if (signal != 2)
         {
             return false;
         }
         else if (signal == 100)
         {
             OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(1, 4, "Message already managed by peer"));
             return true;
         }

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(2, 4, "Sending data size"));
         socketWriter.WriteUInt32((uint)pData.Length);
         await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
         await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(2, 4, "Waiting for size acceptance"));
         signal = await ReadSignal(socketReader);
         if (signal != 3)
         {
             return false;
         }

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(3, 4, "Sending data"));
         socketWriter.WriteBytes(pData);
         await socketWriter.StoreAsync();
         await socketWriter.FlushAsync();

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(3, 4, "Waiting for data acceptance"));
         signal = await ReadSignal(socketReader);
         if (signal != 4)
         {
             return false;
         }

         OnDownloadProgressChangeEvent(new DownloadProgressArgs(4, 4, "Sending completed"));

         socketReader.DetachStream();
         socketWriter.DetachStream();

         socketWriter.Dispose();
         socketReader.Dispose();

         return true;
     }
 }
```

Does anyone has an idea please ? I even dispose socket/datareader/datawriter knowing that I use using keyword...

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is `pSocket`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Hello, i edited the code to add comment. Thank you for pointing that out. pSocket is a StreamSocket returned by PeerFinder.ConnectAsync.

Comment: Consider looking at the code from [this sample](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/24/proximity-in-windows-phone-8/). It was designed for Windows Phone but should work basically the same for Windows Store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However in my understanding there is no difference with what I do. Could you point me out what you think could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!
In my dispatcher timer I was calling async function to browse and to send. But i wasn't waiting (await) these 2 methods so they were executing simultaneously.
PeerFinder refuses to browse and connect at the same time.